# Calculator with mathematical parsing error in python

Tags: python

Code:

```
import re
num=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
opr=['+','-','%','/','*','^']
length=0
#tokens,operators,numbers=[],[],[]
def greater_precedence(op1,op2):
    precedence={'+':0,'-':1,'*':2,'/':3}
    return precedence[op1]>precedence[op2]
def peek(stack):
    return stack[-1] if stack else None
def solve(operator,number):
    print('OP1: ',operator,' ','NP1: ',number)
    v=0
    operator.reverse()
    for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='+':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num1+num2
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='-':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num2-num1
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='*':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num1*num2
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='/':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num2/num1
            operator.remove(j)
    operator.reverse()
    number.append(v)
def bracket_op(operator,number,holder):
    #print('Operation: ',exp)
    #print('Operation 1: ',exp_1)
    print('Operators: ',operator,' ','Numbers: ',number)
    v=0
    lth=len(number)
    top=peek(operator)
    operator.reverse()
    print('Length: ',lth)
    print('OP2: ',operator)
    for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='+' and top=='+':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num2+num1
            operator.remove(j)
    #for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='-' and top=='-':
            num1=number.pop()
            print('S: ',number)
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num1-num2
            operator.remove(j)
    #for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='*'and top =='*':
            num1=number.pop()
            print('M: ',number)
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num1*num2
            operator.remove(j)
    #for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='/'and top =='/':
            num1=number.pop()
            print('D: ',number)
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num2/num1
            operator.remove(j)
    operator.reverse()
    
    
    #print('Operators 1: ',operators,' ','Numbers 1: ',numbers)
    print('holder: ',holder)
    number.insert(holder,v)
    print(number)
        

def evaluate(exp):
    tokens=re.findall('[-]|[(,),+,*,^,%,/]|\d+',exp)
    print('Tokens: ',tokens)
    bracket=False
    holder,value=0,0
    operator,number,brackets=[],[],[]
    for token in tokens:
        if token=='(':
            holder=tokens.index(token)
            operator.append(token)
        elif token==')':
            holder=operator.index('(')
            top=peek(operator)
            while top is not None and top is not '(':
                bracket_op(operator,number,holder)
                top=peek(operator)
            operator.pop()
        else:
            if token in num:
                number.append(float(token))
            else:
                top=peek(operator)
                while top is not None and top is not '(' and greater_precedence(top,token):
                    solve(operator,number)
                    top=peek(operator)
                operator.append(token)
    while peek(operator) is not None:
         solve(operator,number)
            
            
    print('Operators: ',operator,'','Numbers: ',number)
    return number
        

        
def main():
    exp=input("Enter: ")
    print("Answer: {0}".format(evaluate(exp)))
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

Correct Output:

```
Enter: (2+2)*(2+2)
Tokens:  ['(', '2', '+', '2', ')', '*', '(', '2', '+', '2', ')']
Operators:  ['(', '+']   Numbers:  [2.0, 2.0]
Length:  2
OP2:  ['+', '(']
holder:  0
[4.0]
Operators:  ['*', '(', '+']   Numbers:  [4.0, 2.0, 2.0]
Length:  3
OP2:  ['+', '(', '*']
holder:  1
[4.0, 4.0]
OP1:  ['*']   NP1:  [4.0, 4.0]
Operators:  []  Numbers:  [16.0]
Answer: [16.0]
```

Error Output:

```
Enter: (2+2)+(2+2)
Tokens:  ['(', '2', '+', '2', ')', '+', '(', '2', '+', '2', ')']
Operators:  ['(', '+']   Numbers:  [2.0, 2.0]
Length:  2
OP2:  ['+', '(']
holder:  0
[4.0]
Operators:  ['+', '(', '+']   Numbers:  [4.0, 2.0, 2.0]
Length:  3
OP2:  ['+', '(', '+']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\TYBScIT\Sem V\Advanced_Calculator_3.py", line 123, in <module>
   main()
File "F:\TYBScIT\Sem V\Advanced_Calculator_3.py", line 121, in main
   print("Answer: {0}".format(evaluate(exp)))
File "F:\TYBScIT\Sem V\Advanced_Calculator_3.py", line 98, in evaluate
   bracket_op(operator,number,holder)
File "F:\TYBScIT\Sem V\Advanced_Calculator_3.py", line 51, in bracket_op
   num2=number.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Don't know why I get this Error It works fine with correct output and wrong when I replace `'*'` with `'+'`. It works fine without any brackets i.e `'('` and `')'`. Its main aim is to follow BODMAS rule i.e

`(B: Brackets,O:Exponential,D:Division,M:Multiplication,A:Addition,S:Subtraction)`. I have worked far till only with `Brackets,Addition,*,-,/`.
Does not work with
all other maths work related to +,-,/,* with some extend supporting (  )
(2+2)+(2+2)

Comment: You are removing items from `operator` while iterating over it.  This generally results in items being skipped.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. There's too much code here, and it looks like most of it is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Problem: while using ' + ' it shows me list as empty while the list has numbers in it. Example :  (2+2)+(2+2) give error while (2+2)*(2+2) gives me the correct answer

Comment: There are actually multiple errors in this code. If you update to Python 3.8 or higher you'll notice that the interpreter prints some warnings when executing this code. I get `SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
  tokens=re.findall('[-]|[(,),+,*,^,%,/]|\d+',exp)` and also `is not '('` is invalid, that should be `!= '('`.

Comment: @wjandrea is right, you really should create a [mre]. Most of the code here is not necessary to reproduce the problem. If you only include `num`, `peek`, `bracket_op` and then call `bracket_op(['+', '(', '+'], [4.0, 2.0, 2.0], 1)` you'll have the exact same error in about 50 lines instead of 123 lines. I'm sure you can make it even shorter, and you'll likely find the error yourself before you'll complete the question ;-) One thing I can already see is that you cal `number.pop()` twice for each '+' operator, so with the given input it seems your list of numbers is too short, hence the error.

Comment: The code is working fine and all the error are solved. Thanks for the help. Now looking forward to work on the UI of calculator with more functions to be added

Comment: @Swapnil, I'm glad your problem is solved. However, to make this useful for others, please improve your question and provide the answer. Otherwise I suggest deleting your question, since in the current form it's not really useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Back-end Code for BODMAS rule which works correctly by me. In Python 3.8.3 Shell. For Calculating mathematical string using parsing method

#Note:

It works only for 0-9 numbers.It does not work for any float numbers. While float number work is still under work

#Code

```
import re
num=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.']
opr=['+','-','%','/','*','^']
length=0
def greater_precedence(op1,op2):
precedence={'+':0,'-':1,'*':2,'/':3,'^':4}
return precedence[op1]>precedence[op2]
def peek(stack):
    return stack[-1] if stack else None
def solve(operator,number):
    v=0
    operator.reverse()
    for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='+':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num1+num2
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='-':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=float(num2-num1)
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='*':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num1*num2
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='/':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num2/num1
            operator.remove(j)
        if j=='^':
            num1=number.pop()
            num2=number.pop()
            v=num2**num1
            operator.remove(j)
operator.reverse()
number.append(v)
def bracket_op(operator,number):
    v=0
    lth=len(number)
    top=peek(operator)
    operator.reverse()
    number.reverse()
    for i,j in enumerate(operator):
        if j=='+' and top=='+':
            number[0]=number[0]+number[0+1]
            number.remove(number[0+1])
            operator.remove(j)
            top=' '
        if j=='-' and top=='-':
            number[0]=number[0+1]-number[0]
            number.remove(number[0+1])
            operator.remove(j)
            top=' '
        if j=='*'and top =='*':
            number[0]=float(number[0]*number[0+1])
            number.remove(number[0+1])
            operator.remove(j)
            top=' '
        if j=='/'and top =='/':
            number[0]=number[0+1]/number[0]
            number.remove(number[0+1])
            operator.remove(j)
            top=' '
        if j=='^' and top=='^':
            number[0]=number[0+1]**number[0]
            number.remove(number[0+1])
            operator.remove(j)
            top=' '
    operator.reverse()
    number.reverse() 


def evaluate(exp):
    tokens=re.findall('[-]|[(,),+,*,^,%,/]|\d+',exp)
    bracket=False
    holder,value=0,0
    operator,number,brackets=[],[],[]
    for token in tokens:
    if token=='(':
        operator.append(token)
    elif token==')':
        top=peek(operator)
        while top != None and top != '(':
            bracket_op(operator,number)
            top=peek(operator)
        operator.pop()
    else:
        if token in num:
            number.append(float(token))
        else:
            top=peek(operator)
            while top != None and top != '(' and greater_precedence(top,token):
                solve(operator,number)
                top=peek(operator)
            operator.append(token)
while peek(operator) is not None:
     solve(operator,number)
value=number.pop()
return value
        

        
def main():
    exp=input("Enter: ")
    print("Answer: {0}".format(evaluate(exp)))
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

#Note:

Square root wont work as it need UI

If any error are occured while executing this code plzz comment down below